# In DllMain, is DLL_THREAD_DETACH can be occurred without DLL_THREAD_ATTACH?

Tags: windows, dll

If the thread has already created before my DLL got loaded. Then, the thread exit before my DLL unload. The question is:

My DllMain will be notify with `DLL_THREAD_DETACH` or no notification about the exiting thread?

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get the notification.  It is explicitly documented in the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for DllMain:

> There are cases in which the entry-point function is called for a terminating thread even if the entry-point function was never called with DLL_THREAD_ATTACH for the thread:
>
> - The thread was the initial thread in the process, so the system called the entry-point function with the DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH value.
> - The thread was already running when a call to the LoadLibrary function was made, so the system never called the entry-point function for it.

Comment: I have already searched in MSDN before asking question. But, I search that page with `DLL_THREAD_DETACH`. If I read the whole remarks section. I should found an answer without asking. Sorry for my lazy. Anyway, Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1):

No, just will be notified the thread if this thread free the library.

```
BOOL WINAPI FreeLibrary(
 _In_ HMODULE hModule
);
```

Check [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683152(v=vs.85).aspx) out.